# Obtener una parte del texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente texto

> /departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-3.html

Y necesito obtener todo lo que esta luego del 3 guion(-)

Lo primero que pense fue hacer

```
url = /departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-3.html

url[-13:]
```

y me devolvio correctamente

> pagina-3.html

Ahora como puedo solucionar el problema que en vez de un digito el numero sea de dos digitos ejemplo /departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-13.html ya que usando lo anterior me estaria devolviendo

> agina-13.html

que seria incorrecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `rfind( )`, que devuelve *el índice* de la última concondancia encontrada, o `-1` si no hay ninguna. En combinación con el *slicing* de cadenas en python:

```
text = '/departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-3.html'
print( text[text.rfind( '-' ) + 1: ] )
```

Detallo:

- `text.rfind( '-' )`: devuelve la última ocurrencia de `-` en la cadena.
- `+ 1`: **no** queremos la posición del último `-`, sino **la siguiente posición**.
- `text[ inicio : final ]`: *corta* la cadena; devuelve una nueva cadena, desde la posición `inicio` hasta la posición `final`.

Ventajas:

- Es *rápido*: pocas operaciones.
- Es *flexible*: solo necesita un `-` en la cadena, y es fácil de adaptar.

Desventajas:

- Es *flexible*: no comprueba **absolutamente nada**, excepto la presencia de ese `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Si las url siguen el mismo patrón donde después del tercer guión aparece la página podrias utilizar esto:

```
url = '/departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-13.html'
''.join(url.split('-')[3:]) // 'pagina13.html'
```

1. Separas con split indicando que el separador es `'-'` y obtienes una lista
2. Como lo que necesitas esta despues del 3 elemento de la lista los obtienes con `[3:]`
3. Finalmente unes con `join` la lista para que te quede un texto

Comment: mas exacto `print(url.split('-')[-1].split('.')[0])`

Comment: para cuando sea de un digito no funcionaria

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con una expresion regular:

```
import re
url="/departamento-venta-palermo-pagina-3333.html"

num = re.findall('[1-9]\d*|0\d+',url)[0]
print(num)

#solo obtener de pagina en adelante
print(''.join(url.split('-')[-2:]))
```

referencia:
[python re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: si no entendí mal, el necesita que le muestre todo lo que esta después del tercer guión, no solo el numero.